# Post API in java with Multiple payload

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web-services, jax-rs

I want to create `POST AP`I in `java` which accepts multiple `payloads`(file).

Basically rest end point will receive 2 `files` as a `payload` for `post request`. As of now I am creating `API` which accepts only one `payload` as an `Input`. How can I send more than one payload( 2 different files) as an input for one rest end point.

for eg.

```
POST http://localhost:8080/accounts/accountdetails
```

it require 2 file `account.json` and `customer.json` as a part of input.

Is there anyway to do the same? how can I handle them in `API`?

Comment: wouldn't it possible to combine the payloads into one?

Comment: thank you @VN'sCorner  . That also I can do, If i get logic to divide the data of file in code using programming. could you help me if we send data in same file by combining?

Comment: Your model class should have fields defined by combination of the two json. You can write DAO services to parse the model and separate them as desired. I am not sure how complex two json files are though. Do you intent to in-jest the file to DB tables or do something else?

Comment: I need to write data of JSON to DB. I can create DAO and controller etc. I want logic how to receive file in method and split it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer this example, it has explained how you can have multiple file in same payload.
https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-multi-file-upload-example